# Checking if a website is online using a PHP Script

Tags: php, curl, cron

I need to create a PHP script that can successfully check if a website is currently online/still active.

I have a list of around 3000 websites to check, and I want to setup a CRON job to run the script on a daily basis to make sure the sites are still active.

I've done some research and built something using this example:

```
<?php

       if (isDomainAvailible('http://www.css-tricks.com'))
       {
               echo "Up and running!";
       }
       else
       {
               echo "Woops, nothing found there.";
       }

       //returns true, if domain is availible, false if not
       function isDomainAvailible($domain)
       {
               //check, if a valid url is provided
               if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
               {
                       return false;
               }

               //initialize curl
               $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
               curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
               curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
               curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
               curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

               //get answer
               $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

               curl_close($curlInit);

               if ($response) return true;

               return false;
       }
?>
```

But it always times out after 300 or so checks, knowing that this might be a PHP execution issue, I was wondering if there was a better or faster method to check these websites.

Comment: its working script & took 5 sec to execute for single website checking.

Comment: yeah it's a working script, but 5 seconds per site, multiplied by over 3000 sites means 250 minutes which I don't think is a feasible solution?

Comment: You could increase performance by using [multi-curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) feature. It's a bit hard to understand from the official manual how to use it properly. So it's better to use a multi-curl wrapper such as [Rolling Curl Mini](https://github.com/hindmost/rolling-curl-mini) (plug!).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the links are stored in a database, you can add in the db table DATE field, eg 'last_check' and update date after checking.

> but 5 seconds per site, multiplied by over 3000 sites means 250 minutes which I don't think is a feasible solution? – SNpn

Your SQL query should select 'last_check' where the 'last_check' is not equal to the current date. Limit to 10 results per query.

Set your cron to run the php script every minute, from midnight to 6am.

```
* 0-6 * * * *   PATH/TO/YOUR/PHP/SCRIPT
```

Comment: He's not using this as a cron at all ;) Perhaps elaborate a bit more on that

Comment: @Robert He wants to setup a cron job, it said in a post  and I wrote a solution.

Comment: Would you be able to explain the benefits of doing it this way? I'd be creating a smaller query on the database, but I would still need to run the script many times to check over the 3000. As websites, can go offline each day, I would still need to recheck over the 3000 entries every day?

Comment: Maybe your curl script fetch the entire remote site. and it is slow. From what I understand you need a simple php ping function, which will return OK if the remote location there, like description here http://www.thecave.info/php-ping-script-to-check-remote-server-or-website/ . Explain my answer: This is primitive 'queue / worker' php system. Your Cron run php script, that run in the background job that requires a certain amount of time, in your case 5 sec per remote site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use such functions like fopen() if allow_url_fopen directive is On:

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
```

or stream_context_create():

```
$opts = array('http' => array(
    'method'=>"GET",
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: is fopen faster than curl()?

Comment: I haven't made such tests. I have shown possible alternatives